# How to handle with multi buttons on Setclick?

Tags: android

How to handle with multi buttons?

I´m using this code to change SoundOff to soundOff ON click

I dont now how to fix the error

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.gameover);

    //setting the orientation to landscape
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);



    ImageView medaille = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.medaille);
    //adding a click listener

    //Define Logout
    ImageButton LogOut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);

    //Define SoundOn

    ImageButton SoundOn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);

    //Define SoundOff

    ImageButton SoundOff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);

    //getting the button
    ImageButton ButtonOk = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);

    LogOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    SoundOff.setOnClickListener(this);
    SoundOn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ButtonOk.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Version

    //define
    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_score);

    TextView txtsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_score_value);
    txtsView.setText(String.valueOf(GameView.score));

    //Value
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_best_score_value);
    myText.setText(String.valueOf(GameView.Highscorer) );

    TextView txtViews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_best_score);


}



@Override


    public void onClick (View v){

    //Define Logout
    ImageButton LogOut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);

    //Define SoundOn

    ImageButton SoundOn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);

    //Define SoundOff

    ImageButton SoundOff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);

    //getting the button
    ImageButton ButtonOk = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);
    switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.imageButton11:
                //starting game activity
                startActivity(new Intent(this, GameView.class));
                break;

            case R.id.imageButton4:
                //Logout
                startActivity(new Intent(this, GameLogout.class));
                // do your code
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton8:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, GameLogout.class));
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton9:
                play = false;
                SoundOn.setVisibility(View.GONE);//set visibility to false on create
                SoundOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton10:
                play = true;
                SoundOn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//set visibility to false on create
                SoundOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        }

    }
```

I´m getting an error in NullPointerException in the "SoundOn.setVisibility(View.GONE);//set visibility to false on create"

Comment: It´s not duplicate, its an error in the onClick and i dont see what is.

Comment: It simply means your variable SoundOn is a null object

Comment: i think you forgot to add `findViewById` to the SoundOn view.

Comment: "SoundOn" view reference variable is not initialized properly. Initialize the "SoundOn" in your onCreate() method.

Comment: Can you give me the code? whell i have initialize with "
        ImageButton ButtonOk = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);

        ImageView medaille = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.medaille);
        //adding a click listener

        //Define Logout
        ImageButton LogOut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8); "

Answer (score 0):

SoundOn is null; you need to make sure you initialize it.
If you are using Activities a good place is to do it in onCreate after you inflate the view. With something like this:

```
SoundOn = findViewById(R.id.YourViewsId);
```

Comment: I have done that and dont work.

Comment: It does work; you must not be doing it incorrectly. Please give us more of your code to see.

Comment: can i send you a message?

Comment: Sure thing fire away

Comment: Incompatible types error

Answer (score 0):

Find which view was updated is only half the work.
You need to inflate (get runtime object of the view) and modify (change the `visibility`).
Add this before you perform any action off changing the button's view (the top of your switch statments):

```
Button SoundOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.soundOffBtnId) //Use ImageButton instead of Button depends on your code.
Button SoundOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.soundOffBtnId)
```